# How can I call another object while looping using PyroCMS tags

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

Here's how the object looks:

```
[obj1] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 0
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
    )
)
[obj2] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [count] => 10
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [count] => 20
    )
)
```

How can I call `obj2` from the `obj1` loop?

```
{{ obj1 }}
  {{ id }}
    {{ obj2 }}
      {{ count }}
    {{ /obj2 }}
  {{ /obj1 }}
```

This format returns the `id`, but `obj2` doesn't return `counts`.
I want find out the right way to iterate through objects and why `obj2` doesn't call at all.
By the way, I already solved it using the `foreach` format, so I'll just stick to that if its not solvable.

Comment: @Fabio - When editing, please try to observe the rules of English grammar. The first letter in a sentence is capitalized, and the pronoun "I" is also capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Using loops through LEX aren't meant to be cross-referenced like that. So it is not possible. If you wanted to be able to do that, you should be merging the two Objects before and then passing them to the View or wherever else you are passing it.

Comment: thanks for the late reply, anyway i used php code instead :)). 
"f the police" lol